# Tracing the source of - java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I got that error when I ran my Java-Oracle 11g-JDBC code in eclipse. I am only trying to create a table and then add some rows to it.
How can I see which line of code caused that error ? 
Please help.

Comment: Give us the stack trace.

Comment: I enjoy helping others. It isn't about points for me.

Edit: Just looked at your profile. Python is awesome!

Comment: @edhedges - I will first have to figure out how to get a stack trace. Can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: The stack trace is the message Java outputs to the console when it encounters an error.

Comment: @duffymo - Its not possible to accept answers all the time.

Comment: @sweet dreams - it is possible, but the failure to do so depends on circumstances.  Either none of the answers are helpful or you're too lazy to bother to accept one.  Since I don't want to go back and review your history, I assume it's the latter until you prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, run the SQL you are attempting to execute directly against the Oracle database, outside of Java. You will get a more meaningful error message using something like SQL Developer. Fix the SQL there before patching your code.

Comment: This is a good suggestion and it is how I do things, but Java stack traces are usually very easy to debug.

Comment: @edhedges I don't 100% agree that stack traces are always easy to read. But in this specific case, there is obviously a problem with the SQL being executed. Why would you want to perform potentially multiple recompiles when you could format your SQL nicely in a tool like SQL Developer and fix the problem at source.

Comment: I will try that by doing my queries on the DB. Btw, Is there a way to log my SQL queries to a text file or something before they are executed ?

Comment: The stack trace will give you the precise line and file where the error occurred.  How is that hard to read?

Comment: @duffymo You have obviously never encountered stack traces where the actual exception is wrapped and buried in the trace. In this specific case, all the stack trace will point to is the line of Java which ultimately executes the SQL. It may not reveal the problem with the SQL syntax, hence my suggestion of using SQL Developer.

Comment: Of course I have encountered wrapped exceptions; how can you write Java without encountering them from time to time?  I still say it's an easy matter to read them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a table and adding rows to that table, do all these in a stored procedure with IN and OUT parameters, compile the stored procedure (by doing so eliminates all errors) and call this procedure from Java.

This would be helpful in debugging and making code neat and tidy.

Regards